# Do not delay mapped keys with common prefix

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript

What I want to do is have two mappings.  One mapped to `<s-k>`, and one mapped to `<s-k><s-k>`.  What happens right now is that if I press `<s-k>` `vim` delays for `timeoutlen`ms, and if I don't press anything it does the `<s-k>` action, and if I press another `<s-k>` in that time it does the `<s-k><s-k>` action.

However, what I want it to do is do BOTH, i.e. if I press `<s-k>` it will do the `<s-k>` action immediately, and if I press another `<s-k>` in the `timeoutlen` period, it will do the second command as well.

Comment: I think you'll have to build that logic yourself. Write a single mapping for `<s-k>` (btw isn't that just `K`?) that controls whether it's called once or twice (hint: use a global or script variable) and acts accordingly. You can use the `CursorHold` or `CursorMoved` events to reset the variable, that's probably close enough to the `timeoutlen` behavior, if not exactly the same...

Comment: Just to clarify, if I press `KK`, should both mappings take effect? Or only the second?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble both

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to achieve this with regular mappings of `K` and `KK`. If the `K` mapping fires then Vim is necessarily no longer waiting to see if `KK` is typed, and there are no configuration options that can change this behaviour.

There are ways to workaround this, however. filbranden suggested one possible method [in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22607/do-not-delay-mapped-keys-with-common-prefix#comment40919_22607) which [D. Ben Knoble has implemented](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22616/343).

Rather than rely on autocommands to reset the state, I'd probably check the time since we last fired the mapping directly in the mapping itself by using [`reltime()`](http://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#reltime%28%29):

```
function KFunc() abort
  if !exists("s:last_press") || reltimefloat(reltime(s:last_press)) > &timeoutlen / 1000.0
    " do one

    " remember when we fired the mapping
    let s:last_press = reltime()

  else
    " do two

    " reset the time
    unlet s:last_press
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap K :call KFunc()<CR>
```

Comment: reltime was clever. +1 from me.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble FWIW, I upvoted your answer too :).

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this would do:

```
let s:pressed = 0

function KFunc() abort
  let s:pressed += 1
  if s:pressed == 1
    " do one
  else if s:pressed == 2
    " do two
    let s:pressed = 0
  endif
endfunction

augroup ResetPressed
  au!
  au CursorMoved,CursorMovedI,CursorHold,CursorHoldI * let s:pressed = 0
augroup END

nnoremap K :call KFunc()<CR>
```

I included the insert mode variants of cursor moved/hold, but you probably don't need them unless it's an insert-mode map.

As @Rich points out in the comments, CursorHold and friends fire after `'updatetime'`, not `'timeoutlen'`. Changing `'updatetime'` has implications for swap files, and fixing the code seems tedious. That said, I changed `'updatetime'` to 250ms (down from the default 4s) without any adverse effects.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the `Hold` events fire after `'updatetime'` rather than `'timeoutlen'`: by default these are different values, (and `updatetime` also affects the swap file behaviour, which you should be aware of before changing it.)

Comment: Thinking about it further, I guess if it were a problem, you could make the function/autocommand change `updatetime` to  match `timeoutlen` only while it's waiting to see if the second part of the mapping is going to fire.

Comment: @Rich interesting solution! Good points (ive edited them in).