# How do I make the h key go to prev tab if at start of file?

Tags: key-bindings, buffers, tabbed-user-interface

And, to get back again: how do I make the `l` key go to next tab, if at end of file?

I'd also like to make `hh` go to previous buffer, and `ll` go to next buffer. I know that'll add a delay to recognising the `h`/`l` keys, and slow down navigation, and I wonder is there a way to tell vim to

> Only check for "hh" at start of file, and only check for "ll" at end of file

Comment: This is doable, but I'd recommend getting used to `gt` and `gT`. If you're looking to cycle buffers, tpope's unimpaired uses `]b` and `[b` for `:bnext` and `:bprev`, respectively, which I find quite nice. `:ls` followed by `:buffer ` is also quite nice

Comment: @jalanb I'm not sure whether you also had intended to award the bounty that ended up expiring to my answer: if so, I appreciate it. Thanks for the accept, either way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Ben and statox, I wouldn't necessarily recommend this, but it is possible:

```
function FirstPress(c1) abort
  let now = reltime()
  while reltimefloat(reltime(now)) < &timeoutlen / 1000.0
    " See if the user has typed another character
    let c2 = getchar(0)

    if c2 != 0
      " The user typed something. Was it another h?
      if c2 == char2nr(a:c1)
        " The user typed a double h, switch buffers
        if a:c1 == 'h'
          bprevious
        else
          bnext
        endif
      else
        " The user typed something else. Switch tabs and replay what they typed
        call feedkeys((a:c1 == 'h' ? 'gT' : 'gt') . nr2char(c2), 't')
      endif
      return
    endif
  endwhile

  " The user didn't press anything. Switch Tabs
  if a:c1 == 'h'
    tabprevious
  else
    tabnext
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> h (getpos('.')[1] == 1 && getpos('.')[2] == 1) ? ':call FirstPress("h")<CR>' : 'h'
nnoremap <expr> l (getpos('.')[1] == line('$') && (getpos('.')[2] == col('$') - 1 \|\| col('$') == 1)) ? ':call FirstPress("l")<CR>' : 'l'
```

It works by mapping the single `h` and `l` keypresses only, and then in that mapping, checking if the user presses the given key a second time, and acting accordingly.

See also my answer to [this recent similar, but slightly different question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22617/343) where the OP wanted to do the first mapping immediately and then perform the second as well if performed within `timeoutlen`.

Comment: You got me at "wouldn't necessarily recommend this", but just reading yours brought my vim code up a level. Yesterday I kinda knew those things were possible, today I have `feedkeys()`! All I do all day is feed keys to vim! 

This is could be a life-changer...

Comment: `&timeout` is an "option" http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.3

Comment: Which defaults to `1000` http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'timeoutlen', but easily changed with `tm`

Comment: @jalanb Glad I could help! :D

Comment: @jalanb I went a bit overboard with the `feedkeys` use in my original answer. I've updated it to only use it where necessary (for replaying the keypress that the user typed).

Answer (score 1):

> how do I make the l key go to next tab, if at end of file

For this part make a function which checks that the following two conditions are satisfied:

1. The value of `line(".")`, which is the current line number, and `line("$")`, which is the number of all lines in a file, match
2. The current column value, obtained with `col(".")`, and the length of the current line, obtained with `strlen(getline("."))`, match.

This means that you're on the last line, on the last column (i.e. the last character in the file).

I hope this pushes you in the right direction.