# vim-wiki mapping <leader>ww causing delay in another mapping

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin-vimwiki

I'm using Neovim and my init.vim has a quick save mapping as below

```
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>
```

Since i installed vim-wiki, there's a noticeable delay in the execution of w because of vim-wiki mapping ww.

I tried removing the mapping with

```
nunmap <leader>ww
```

and also tried

```
nmap <leader>vw <leader>ww
```

but the delay persists. I use the quick save quite often so the delay is a bit annoying.

Is there a way to remove or remap it to

```
nmap <leader>vw :VimwikiIndex
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not delay mapped keys with common prefix](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22607/do-not-delay-mapped-keys-with-common-prefix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

- map to the `<Plug>` sequence for the command you need yourself (vimwiki won't create the mappings if it detects that you already did)

```
" :help vimwiki-global-mappings
" :help vimwiki-local-mappings
nmap <leader>vw <Plug>VimwikiIndex
```

I don't like this solution because there are a lot of `<leader>w` mappings, and any one of them is going to conflict with yours and cause a delay.

- Change vimwiki's prefix:

```
" :help g:vimwiki_map_prefix
let g:vimwiki_map_prefix = '<leader>v'
```

---

A third option that requires more work is to build your own wiki system. My plugin [wiki-md](https://github.com/benknoble/wiki-md) attempts to make this easy by leveraging a bunch of vim builtins. More info provided if desired, but I will note that wiki-md provides more of a skeleton on which you build your own features; it doesn't come with everything out of the box that something like vimwiki does.